# Order sample product on view page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sample

I tried this tutorial https://gist.github.com/WazzaJB/8083094
to add sample product to cart, it creates sample product on admin but it doesn't add this sample product to cart, it redirect me to home page.
please help me, i'm using magento 1.9